# mysql can not setup remote access

Tags: mysql

Trying to set up mysql for access from any host.

> > show grants for 'root'@'%';
>
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION

**my.cnf**

```
[root@p419386 etc]# cat my.cnf
#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

Files in /etc/my.cnf.d: client.cnf  enable_encryption.preset  mysql-clients.cnf  server.cnf  tokudb.cnf
None contains `skip-networking`

In **server.cnf**

```
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

I use CentOS 7, `uname -a` gives

```
Linux p419386 2.6.32-042stab120.16 #1 SMP Tue Dec 13 20:58:28 MSK 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

MySQL server is `10.1.21-MariaDB MariaDB Server`

Still can't connect from remote host :(

Problem definitely not in network or firewall.

**Are above settings correct?** What's wrong?

After all **the problem was found** in iptables rules. So MySQL config is OK!

Comment: Does your `my.cnf` still contain `skip-networking`? Consider [giving this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address) a better look. It should have most of the information?

Comment: Have added some more info in question. None of configs contains skip-networking.

Comment: Did you, as suggested in one of the posts on that other question, include `# skip-networking` in the `server.cnf`? As we now know you're using Linux, what distribution are you using and which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: MariaDB 10.1 on CentOS 7

Comment: How are you trying to connect from a remote host? What error message are you getting? How did you verify that your firewall configuration is correct? Did you check the command line parameters it's started with? [This](http://www.itworld.com/article/2861513/how-to-configure-mysql-and-mariadb-to-accept-remote-connections.html) article seems to indicate it might be an issue.

Comment: Running `mysql -h <host>` from remote host gives `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '<host>' (113)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52574/discussion-between-alexey-and-seth).

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the configuration you have (as far as you explicitly posted it and told us what's in it) it looks like it should work. At least the [official MariaDB KB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/) would indicate this.

As such you might either be missing something within those configuration files or you're facing a different problem. While you did say that the problem can't bet network or firewall related, your latest error `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '<host>' (113)` would indicate that it still could be an issue.

You could try to connect to your local IP (127.0.0.1) on your server using the mysql commend. Looking at the question I linked you would use:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
```

If you're able to establish a connection using that command you'd know that your MariaDB was up and running and accepting IP based connections.

Now what might be happening is that it doesn't bind to the external IP addresses (maybe try to set just your external IP for `bind-host`) or your firewall (client or server) or another network component could be interfering and blocking the connection.

To check whatever the server is binding to you could run (as as root or with sudo):

```
netstat -l -n -p
```

That should get you a line like the following:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
...
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1234/mysqld
...
```

As you can see, in this case, the MySQL server is running point to the localhost address on port 3306.